# What cleric and wizard spells can I use to maximize my immunities?

Tags: spells, dnd-3.5e, optimization, immunities

I'm currently trying to maximize the amount of things my character is immune to. My current situation is:

- Aasimar/Lesser Aasimar/Saint.
- Bard 1/Sha'ir 1/Geomancer 2/Incantatrix 3/Ur Priest 1/Mystic Theurge 4.

I'm using my daily pool of Metamagic Effect as 24-hour buffs to great effect. Apart from practical spells (fly, haste) I'm aiming at immunity buffs. In total I'm currently immune to:

- Mind Control (Disobedience),
- Crowd Control (Freedom of Movement),
- Acid, Cold, Electricity, Petrification (Saint),

...I also have a decent amount of Saves, although far from perfect. Currently more or less:

- +14/+10/+30.

Now the problem I have: I'm pretty vulnerable to all sorts of **poisons, diseases and most importantly ability drain/damage**. I have some Metamagic Effect uses still free to utilize and I can replace some of my utility spells if needed. **I'm looking for spells that have a duration (thus are eligible to use Metamagic Effect with Persistence on them) that grant me such immunities.**

Since my character is a support / buffer / controller (known in some circles as God-Wizard build, although due to access to 2 spell classes I've now surpassed that concept) my goal is to be impervious to pretty much anything so I can keep buffing, debuffing and saving my team for as long as they can still stand without need to care about my own safety.

Answers that acquire me to get slightly higher level are acceptable. I have access to level 5 spells from both Wiz and Clr spell lists right now, it will be 6 and 6 respectively on next level, 6 and 7 on another level and so on.

DISCLAIMER: No Wish shenaningans, no Pun-Pun, no Infinite loops just regular spells, fair and square. I don't want to break the system.

Comment: You need to add some kind of constraints here. You could Pun-Pun yourself immunity to everything if you wanted. Undead would trivially cover all of the immunities you’ve called out. And I know you’re aware of those options, so if you aren’t using them, we need to know what the limitations are here.

Comment: This is why I'm looking specifically for spells from Cleric or Wiz lists. Short term buffs that I can prolong to 24 hours. Fair and square things that can be dispelled from me, but it will take long time to strip me of my defenses. I'll add the no-wish-BS line to clarify though.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

*Veil of Undeath* (*Spell Compendium*) is the deluxe option. You're not going to get regular access to it for three more levels, though.

*Death Ward* should definitely be on your daily buff list, unless you spend the 25k on some *+1 soulfire armor* (*Book of Exalted Deeds*), which is an excellent investment. That covers death effects and energy drain.

*Sheltered Vitality* (SC) will cover ability damage and drain from all sources. If you're still worried about other types of poison and disease (though I wouldn't be) there's *neutralize poison* and you could pay the 7.4k for a *periapt of health*.

Finally, if you (or an ally) can somehow get access to the paladin spell *favor of the martyr* (*SC*), it provides a laundry list of immunities, including to stunning and daze, which can otherwise be quite hard to become immune to.

Comment: I didn't think of items. Thanks for mentioning that. I have Crafter Cohort specced for Wondrous Items so I can get those very cheap.

Comment: Awesome recommendations. Small questions regarding them though: Is there any way to remove material cost of Veil of Death? And is there any way to add Paladin spell to Cleric list? Team is mostly on the neutral to lawful evil axis so Paladin will never fly.

Comment: @NecXelos There are evil paladin variants. Also [this list](https://forums.giantitp.com/showthread.php?187851-3-5-Lists-of-Necessary-Magic-Items) is a classic that never gets old. There are several "negation" sections.

Comment: @NecXelos Also, undead type isn't immune to mental ability damage, so combination of other spells is better, I believe.

Comment: Note that the *SC* version of *veil* has a much more manageable material component; you might be looking at the now-defunct *Libris Mortis* version. And getting access to *favor of the martyr* is tricky. Easiest will be *limited wish*, accepting the xp cost for big fights. You could use a wand, but realistically no paladin has Craft Wand (or any other item creation feats).

Comment: @Prevarications of course, Craft Wand. Thank You very much, my brain works slowly today. My Crafter Cohort is an Artificer (obviously) so I don't need to give a damn about spell requirements while crafting wands :)

Comment: @Prevarications true, I was looking at Libris Mortis and that 1000 GP daily gold sink kind of scared me. Thanks again, this means it will be my daily spell in place of Disobedience once I reach level 8 spells.